# Getting error with if else statement in python using input

Tags: python, if-statement

When I run the code below I get a a syntax error. What's the issue and how can I rectify it?
Thanks!

```
m = input("enter number between -5 and +5: ")
m = int(m)
if m < 0:
  print( m, " is less than 0")
  elif m > 0:
    print(m, " is greater than 0")
  else:
    print(m, " is equal to 0")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your indentation on the 5th line is wrong. The `if`, `elif`, and `else` need to be at the same indentation level.

Comment: @dataj mark the answer as accepted if it works